# convert HTML controls to ASP server controls

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, aspx-user-control

I have a bunch of HTML controls created in a design. Now I want to convert them to ASP server controls. Can someone suggest me how to do this? Is it just enough to add runat attribute?

Comment: What does this question has to do with asp.net mvc tag ?

Comment: Server controls aren't compatible with MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add `runat="server"` and an id to access it `id="whatever"`

Example:

```
<input type="text" value="find" />

<input type="text" runat ="server" id="textId" value="find" />
```

You can use the id to access it in the codeBehind.

Alternatively, I think you can right click a control in the designer and select `run as server control`

Comment: Upon adding the runat attribute and then when we try to inspect the element, will the runat attribute show up there?